# Sharepoint workflow approval

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, workflow

How can I set up a new workflow approval?

1. I have a SP List.
2. Once the user (note there are multiple users) has submitted a new item, a workflow will be started.
3. It will send an email to the designated Approver (example: supervisor of the user)
4. Once the supervisor of the user approved, this will be re-routed to me (as the Site owner) and will also be subject for my approval.

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 1):

You can go throuh the below article step by step!

[Reference1](http://aspetraining.com/resources/blog/how-to-create-an-approval-workflow-sharepoint-2013), [Reference2](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sharepointdesigner/2012/08/15/a-sample-sharepoint-2013-approval-workflow-which-can-be-recalled-by-the-initiator/),[Reference3](http://techbrij.com/sharepoint-designer-2013-workflow-dynamic-approvers)

First & Third reference have the walk through for the create Approval Workflow.

Hope this will hepl you!

Comment: Hi ram, thansks for your reply! will check this once i got home and will let you know if its going to work out!

Answer (score 0):

Please refer following steps :

1. Open SharePoint Designer.
2. Create a list workflow.
3. GoTo **Action** => **Start Approval Process**.
4. Click on "these users" and select the participants (these are your first and second approver) Please refer screenshot.

[image]

5. Set workflow to run on item created/changed according to your need.
6. Publish Workflow.
7. Done.

Comment: Dear Rohit, thank you for your reply! :) Will check once  i got home and try the steps you have provided. :) Will this depends on the user? I have aropund 50 users